# Error: specify a date within the permissible range

Tags: sapb1

We are trying to create a Sales Order and are receiving "specify a date within the permissible range".

So after some Googling, I have seen that the most common reason for this is that your Due Date and Document Date are not within the same Posting Period as the Posting Date.

As seen here in the SAP documentation:

https://help.sap.com/saphelp_sbo900/helpdata/en/e4/428eaaf7d941448a591699918fcc06/frameset.htm

However, as you can see from our screen shot, this is already correct. Further, this only started happening overnight and no one touched a thing, I swear! :)

Does anyone have any advice please?
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: link you posted gives this message "Sorry, we can't find the page you're looking for"

Comment: That's weird... I can see it... well trust me that it's within the period of time. Is there anything else that would cause this error?

Comment: @Aaqib, I can open it as well.

Answer (score 0):

I did not fully trust being told that NOTHING had changed. By clicking on the Yellow arrow beside the Posting Period in the posting period window, I saw that the document date range had been changed from ending in May 2018 to May 2017. Job done. This was found by sticking close to the error message and not straying too far in my thinking. Reagan had it right! Trust but verify! ;)